# Safari Extension to restyle Gmail?

Tags: gmail

I'm looking for something similar to the ["Snow Leopard" extension for Reader](http://mariusth.channelwood.org/SafariExtensions/#GoogleReaderSnowLeopard).
Also, I think the MobileMe look would look good on Gmail.

Comment: Any particular reason using Safari instead of Chrome?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a recommendation for a browser extension.

Comment: @ale sounds good to me. It is nearly 7 years old... And the mentioned platforms are either dated or don't exist. To be fair, this predates "Web application recommendation requests" as off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it works with Safari, but Google Redesigned is a great collection of userstyles for Gmail and other Google web apps: http://www.globexdesigns.com/gr/